# How do you fake your location with the google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am using the google maps API to gain a users location:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

To test this I would like to fake the location however setting chromes geo location does not work as it seems to ignore this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the maps api itself you can't fake the position because it uses the geolocation functionality of your browser. If you want to fake your geolocation in Chrome you can do it like this:

Press F12 to open the **Developer Console**. Change to the tab **Console** and open the menu with the 3 dots icon. Select **More Tools --> Sensors** and change the default value for the **Geolocation** from "No override" to a preset or enter own coordinates. Now reload the page and see how it works.

I tested it right now on [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/geolocation) Google Geolocation Tutorial page and inside an own application with Google maps. Good luck!

It works the same way in:

- Vivaldi
- Opera (use CTRL + SHIFT + C instead of F12)

Different for:

- Firefox (I think you have to use an extension)
- Internet Explorer 11 (F12, Tab **Emulation**, Geolocation --> *on* and enter lat and lon

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as mentioned in the question. I am using only the location api that I have linked not the whole maps api so it is different to what you have linked.

Comment: Did you reload the page? Which version are you using and did you deactivate Geolocation extensions? #edit: A right sorry...because you just wrote google maps API and tagged it.

Comment: I tried in incognito mode so and it did not request my current location as normal html5 geo look up does. I assume it falls back to ip look up as per the docs when google does not already have a location. It does however return my long and lat so the code is working

Comment: Yes, it seems to use mobile cell data / wifi to get the location - due to that it will be different. Which extensions did you test? Location Guard? So if it's using your IP think about using a proxy to check if the position changes.